# Alias IP is not working in Windows Server 2016, Data Center instance in Google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I created a "Windows Server 2016 DataCenter, Desktop experience" machine in Google cloud. I also setup an alias IP range to bind multiple sites to the server.

But when I try to ping any IP inside the provided "IP alias" range, I get a `request timeout`. Do I need to enable any other service to start working Alias IP?

Thanks,
Sachin Saxena

Comment: Have you bound any address from the IP alias range to the network interface in Windows network settings? You should see appropriate results in Windows command prompt: `ipconfig`, `route print`.

Comment: Thanks. After adding in Windows network it is working.

Comment: Nice to hear that you've managed to get it working. I'll post a short answer then.

Answer (score 0):

An address from the IP alias range should be bound to the network interface in Windows network settings. It would be better having a separate network interface to serve IP address range.

Start => Settings => Network & Internet => Change adapter options => right-click on the Ethernet adapter => Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) => Properties

=> Use the following IP address

=> Advanced (to bind extra addresses as needed)

Bound addresses and appropriate changes in the routing table can be checked afterwards in Windows command prompt: `ipconfig`, `route print`.